# LWJGL Test Error - Could not find or load main class java

Tags: java, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

I've just downloaded the `LWJGL` archive and unzipped, and am testing via command line as specified on the site. However, I can't seem to get it to run.

```
java -cp .:res:jar/lwjgl.jar:jar/lwjgl_test.jar:jar/lwjgl_util.jar:jar/lwjgl_fmod3.jar:jar/lwjgl_devil.jar:jar/jinput.jar: -Djava.library.path=native/macosx org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest
```

Results in the error message as follows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java
```

Used **JDK 1.6** and **1.7** on a **Mac OS 10.6.8**

Comment: Replace `:` with `;`.

Comment: It just started working all of a sudden. The semicolon just throws a huge bunch of errors. Thanks for the help.